# Does a cURL request in php resolve a subdomain locally?

Tags: php, curl

I have a VPS Ubuntu Server 14.04 Trusty and I would like to know if the usage of cURL library resolves a subdomain DNS locally.

I have 2 domains at the same server that one of them are a subdomain (Webservice).

If I make a cURL request for the webservice, Will the request be resolved locally or will pass through the internet?

If passed through the internet how do I resolve it locally?

(I'm hoping that this locally resolution would slow the amount of time for the given request.)

Comment: php will use the system resolver, and it'll do the dns lookup. you'll get whatever IP the resolver decides on. e.g. full-blown DNS lookup, or grabbing a value from /etc/hosts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

> If passed through the internet how do I resolve it locally?

Connect to the local IP address instead of the public one.

Which VPS service are you using? Amazon EC2 for example lists private and public IP addresses with each instance.